# Using the dict() constructor with "illegal" variable names

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary

I have an application whose configuration file is itself a Python script containing a dict of nested dicts (I am aware that this is not considered best practice). It looks abit like this:

```
config={'section-1': {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'},
        'section-2': {'param3': 'value3', 'param4': 'value4'},
        'section-1': {'param5': 'value5', 'param6': 'value6'}
       }
```

See what has happened there, someone has accidentally repeated `section-1`! This is quite difficult to trap in a unit test, unless instead of importing the file in Python, I instead treat it as a text file and parse it. I had thought I could use `dict()` for this, to create an identical structure e.g.

```
config=dict(section-1={'param1', 'value1'}, section-1={'param2': 'value2'})
```

Trapping this problem with `SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated` but unfortunately I actually get `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`. There is no scope to replace the section names with ones that don't contain a `-`, nor to replace this with a classic INI file or similar, that ship has long sailed. Is there any way I can trap duplicate keys?

Comment: What happens when the app loads the config file? Since it is a python file, it will be processed by the python interpreter which will only keep the last declaration. I wonder why your parser has to do anything different - it makes sense if you are creating a test-case to catch such errors...

Comment: I don't want to let the second `section-1` overwrite the first as that is certainly  mistake by whoever is editing the file. It should be un-check-in-able if its in that state (we have a pre-commit trigger to run the unit tests).

Comment: If you treat it as a text file, preprocess it to change the form of the problem labels before parsing.

Comment: you could create your own custom dict

Answer (score 1):

Following what davidc said: "treat it as a text file, preprocess it to change the form of the problem labels before parsing", this worked for your example...

```
from ast import literal_eval
from collections import defaultdict

config = '''{'section-1': {'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2'},
    'section-2': {'param3': 'value3', 'param4': 'value4'},
    'section-1': {'param5': 'value5', 'param6': 'value6'},
    'section-1': {'param7': 'value7', 'param8': 'value8'}
   }'''

cfg=config.replace('{','[').replace('}',']').replace(
    ' ','').replace('[','[(').replace(']',')]').replace(
    ',','),(').replace(':',',').replace('\n','')

parsed_config = {}
keys = defaultdict(int)

for s, d in literal_eval(cfg):
    if s in parsed_config:
        keys[s] += 1
        parsed_config[s+'('+str(keys[s])+')'] = dict(d)
    else:
        parsed_config[s] = dict(d)

print(parsed_config)

# {'section-1(2)': {'param7': 'value7', 'param8': 'value8'}, 
#  'section-2': {'param4': 'value4', 'param3': 'value3'}, 
#  'section-1': {'param2': 'value2', 'param1': 'value1'}, 
#  'section-1(1)': {'param6': 'value6', 'param5': 'value5'}}
```

You could extend the logic to test for repeated param, value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

My answer below will ***not*** work since `config` will not have both values present when it is processed! I will leave my answer here anyway.

One option is to create another dict where you will dump the keys from dict:

```
new_config = {}
for k, v in config.iteritems():
    if k in new_config:
        print 'Error: Overwriting key %s' % k
        sys.exit()
    new_config[k] = v
```

Comment: it doesn't work because `config.iteritems()` only has `section-2 {'param4': 'value4', 'param3': 'value3'}
section-1 {'param6': 'value6', 'param5': 'value5'}`